# Illustrator CC "Undo" disabled

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Using Illustrator CC, "Undo" stopped working. "Undo" is still enabled from the Edit menu, but does nothing; neither does Ctrl/Cmd+Z.

The disabled "Undo" is somehow linked to the artwork. In a new document, "Undo" works. But, if I paste a particular set of artwork objects, the problem re-appears. Also, an asterisk (*) next to the filename appears nearly immediately after saving the document.

I tried re-installing Illustrator and deleting the preferences file, neither of which helped.

Comment: So if you create a new document and place a circle and then go to Edit -> Undo. It does nothing?

Comment: Correct. Only way to undo any change is to "Revert".

Comment: Trash app preferences. Even a reinstall retains old preference files in many instances.

Comment: Thanks, Metis. I did as you suggested. But, it didn't change anything. However, I did find the problem is somehow linked to the artwork.

Comment: It may be related to disk space. Illustrator used to have a preference for limiting how many Undo's are allowed. The more Undo's that the app has to memorize, the more scratch disk that needs to be converted from your hard drive to virtual RAM. A large placed image requires more memory to Undo than a simple vector line. Have you tried freeing up a couple of Gigs?

Comment: I finally nailed down the particular object. It's a simple symbol of an arrow! How can a simple, single-path shape disable undo?

Answer (score 1):

I finally nailed down the particular object that was causing the issue. The culprit is a symbol of an arrow, believe it or not. I delete the instance of the symbol and "Undo" functionality is restored. Of course, once I undo the delete, the problem comes back along with the arrow.

How can a simple, single-path shape disable undo?

I even used a built-in symbol that comes with Illustrator, Arrow6.

Comment: I can't replicate the problem using the Arrow6 symbol. For me it has no effect on Undo availability.

Comment: Just came across this problem. [This Adobe Forums thread](https://forums.adobe.com/message/8480431) identified the problem for me. It's related to Dynamic Symbols. Changing the symbols back to Static fixed it.